# Select Where IN todos os registros

Tags: php, mysql, select, where

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Senhores , vai procurei por dias a repostas para esta minha duvida que acho que é boba , mas não consegui.

criei um view que traz  Matricula | Nome     |Cargo |Turno |    CentroCusto |    CodTreina  |    Status

Fiz este select :

```
SELECT * FROM vw_treina_func TF WHERE TF.CodTreina IN (1,16,22,33,75,97110, 115, 158,161,164,173,)
```

Este select esta trazendo os funcionários que tem  um ou outro treinamento dos código dentro do IN. O que estou precisando é que de alguma forma só trouxesse  os funcionários  que tenha todos  e não um o outro como esta acontecendo.

a view tem informarção da tabela treina_func  join  tabela funcionarios join func_area

Segue o codigo de deu certo:

```
SELECT a.Codigo, a.descricao, fa.CentroCusto, f.MatriculaSese,r.Descricao, f.nome
FROM area a 
INNER JOIN treina_area ta ON ta.CodArea = a.Codigo 
INNER JOIN treina_func tf ON tf.CodTreina = ta.CodTreina 
INNER JOIN funcionarios f ON f.MatriculaSese = tf.MatriculaSese
INNER JOIN func_area fa ON f.MatriculaSese = fa.MatriculaSese
INNER JOIN area r ON r.Codigo = fa.CentroCusto
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CodArea, Codtreina, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT iita.CodTreina) FROM treina_area iita WHERE iita.CodArea = ita.CodArea) numTreinos FROM treina_area ita ) TodosTreinosArea ON TodosTreinosArea.CodArea = ta.CodArea AND TodosTreinosArea.Codtreina = ta.CodTreina 
WHERE a.Codigo = 2 and fa.CentroCusto <> 2 GROUP BY a.descricao, f.MatriculaSese, f.nome 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tf.CodTreina) = COUNT(CASE WHEN TodosTreinosArea.CodTreina IS NOT NULL THEN TodosTreinosArea.CodTreina END) AND COUNT(DISTINCT tf.CodTreina) = MAX(TodosTreinosArea.numTreinos) ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Cara o in realmente funciona desse jeito, ele trás caso qualquer item da lista do IN bata...

Não é viavel fazer um 
`SELECT * FROM vw_treina_func TF WHERE TF.CodTreina = 1 and TF.CodTreina = 16 and TF.CodTreina = 22 and TF.CodTreina = 33 and TF.CodTreina = 75 and TF.CodTreina = 97110 and TF.CodTreina =  115 and TF.CodTreina =  158 and TF.CodTreina = 161 and TF.CodTreina = 164 and TF.CodTreina = 173 `

Comment: obrigado, gente estou testando todas as alternativas esta com and eu tentei o exemplo que informei no IN  esta vindo de um select , mesmo tratanto no php fazendo um loop para gerar todos o and não traz  resultado  nenhum  registro e sei que no exemplo informado é para traz  30 funcionários. Fiz este select  direto no banco e mesmo assim não traz resultado com and.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode tentar algo assim:

```
SELECT CodFuncionario
  FROM vw_treina_func TF 
 WHERE TF.CodTreina IN (1, 16, 22, 33, 75, 97, 110, 115, 158, 161, 164, 173)
GROUP BY CodFuncionario
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TF.CodTreina) = 12
```

A parte importante é a instrução: HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TF.CodTreina) = 12
Isto irá limitar os resultados aos funcionários que têm 12 CodTreina diferentes.

**Edit após comentário do @LucianoSilva**

**O objectivo é, identificar quais os funcionários que efectuaram todos os treinos para a área seleccionada.**

Como exemplo criei uma pequena base de dados com algumas das tabelas do seu modelo.

```
CREATE TABLE area
(
  cod_area  INT,
  descricao NVARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE treino_area
(
  cod_treina  INT,
  cod_area INT
);

CREATE TABLE funcionario
(
  cod_func  INT,
  nome      NVARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE treino_func
(
  cod_func   INT,
  cod_treina INT
);
```

De seguida carreguei alguns dados de teste

```
INSERT INTO area(cod_area, descricao)VALUES
(1, 'Area A1'),
(2, 'Area B2');

INSERT INTO treina_area(cod_treina, cod_area)VALUES
(1, 1), -- Area A1 treino 1
(2, 1), -- Area A1 treino 2
(2, 2); -- Area B2 treino 2

INSERT INTO funcionario(cod_func, nome)VALUES
(1, 'Jorge'),
(2, 'Manuel'),
(3, 'Pedro');

INSERT INTO treina_func(cod_func, cod_treina)VALUES
(1, 1), -- Jorge treino 1
(1, 2), -- Jorge treino 2
(2, 1), -- Manuel treino 1
(3, 2); -- Pedro treino 2
```

A seguinte query irá devolver os funcionários que efectuaram todos os treinos para a area "Area A1".

```
SELECT a.cod_area,
       a.descricao,
       f.cod_func,
       f.nome
  FROM area a
 INNER JOIN treina_area ta
    ON ta.cod_area = a.cod_area
 INNER JOIN treina_func tf
    ON tf.cod_treina = ta.cod_treina
 INNER JOIN funcionario f
    ON f.cod_func = tf.cod_func
 LEFT JOIN 
 (
    SELECT cod_area,
           cod_treina,
           (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT iita.cod_treina) FROM treina_area iita WHERE iita.cod_area = ita.cod_area) numTreinos
      FROM treina_area ita       
 ) TodosTreinosArea
    ON TodosTreinosArea.cod_area = ta.cod_area
   AND TodosTreinosArea.cod_treina = ta.cod_treina
 WHERE a.cod_area = 1
 GROUP BY a.descricao, f.cod_func, f.nome
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tf.cod_treina) = COUNT(CASE WHEN TodosTreinosArea.cod_treina IS NOT NULL THEN TodosTreinosArea.cod_treina END)
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT tf.cod_treina) = MAX(TodosTreinosArea.numTreinos)
 ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Resultado:

```
cod_area    descricao   cod_func    nome
1           Area A1     1           Jorge
```

Apenas o funcionário Jorge é devolvido pois é o único que completou todos os treinos necessários: o treino 1 e o treino 2. O Pedro não é listado porque apenas efectuou o treino 2 - falta-lhe completar o treino 1.

O resultado quando a area seleccionada é a "Area B2" são os seguintes, pois tanto o Jorge como o Pedro completaram o treino 2:

```
cod_area    descricao   cod_func    nome
2           Area B2     1           Jorge
2           Area B2     3           Pedro
```

Fica aqui também o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a26b3/10) como exemplo.

Comment: O IN é resultado de um select da tabela treina_area o qual tem todos os treinamentos relacionados a área e conforme seleciona um codigo de area a quantidade de treinamento vai alterar

Comment: Muito obrigado bruno fiz algumas alterações e deu certo. Vou editar colocar o código pois não sei colocar aqui no comentário.

Answer (score 2):

Suponho que há uma tabela de funcionários e uma de treinamentos, certo?

Seria qualquer coisa como:

```
DECLARE @QUANTIDADE_TREINAMENTOS int

SELECT @QUANTIDADE_TREINAMENTOS = count(*) FROM Treina

SELECT DISTINCT
    CodFunc,
    (SELECT count(*) from vw_treina_func TF2 where TF2.CodFunc = vw_treina_func.CodFunc AND TF2.CodTreina = vw_treina_func.CodTreina) as quantidade
FROM
    vw_treina_func TF
WHERE
    quantidade = @QUANTIDADE_TREINAMENTOS
```

Isso traz somente os registros da view que tiverem a mesma quantidade de treinamentos que for a quantidade de registros na tabela de treinamentos.

Comment: Perdão mas nesse caso ele vai trazer apenas se o "func" bater com todas as correspondências da tabela Treina? ou se bater apenas uma ele ja seleciona

Comment: Ops, cometi um erro. Já corrigirei.

Comment: Ok, agora está corrigido.

Comment: Cara uma duvida que talvez seja pertinente, e se ele quiser apenas estes códigos citados acima e nao a tabela toda? teria uma maneira facil e compacta de resolver isso ? ou ele deveria colocar um `where` gigante com varios `and ` igual citei acima ?

Comment: @MeAjudaSilvio se quiser apenas os códigos acima, basta aplicar a cláusula "in" da pergunta ao `select` que preenche o valor da variável `@QUANTIDADE_TREINAMENTOS`. Infelizmente esse é um caso não tão comum em SQL, não consigo pensar em uma solução **genérica** com menos código. Mas para uma solução não genérica, [a resposta do Bruno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/203177/1658) é a mais direta.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

você deve ter uma tabela com os treinamentos então seria:

**Para pegar a quantidade total de matérias**

```
declare @qtdTreinamento bigint

SELECT qtdTreinamento  = (SELECT DISTINCT CodTreina FROM ***TREINAMENTO*** WHERE CodTreina IN (1,16,22,33,75,97110, 115, 158,161,164,173))

**Selecionar somente os que têm o total informado**

select * from **vw_treina_func**  where Matricula in (select matricula from vw_treina_func group by matricula having count(*) = @qtdTreinamento)
```

Comment: Sim coloquei o DER para facilitar o entendimento tenho um tabela treinamento e uma que relaciona  o treinamento a area que é a treina_area. vou testar a sua solução.